# Laravel on Google Cloud Compute Engine - could not find driver

Tags: laravel-5, google-compute-engine

On laravel I'm trying to do a sqlite connection but I got an `could not find driver` error

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

I already created the file `database/database.sqlite`

/etc/php/apache2/php.ini

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_ftp.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=php_snmp.dll

;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
```

I have `php7.0` and `php7.0-mysql` installed on my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I need to install sqlite with apt-get

`sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3`